# Use `npm start` with --inspect flag?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way for me to run `npm start` and pass in the --inspect flag?

`npm --inspect start` doesn't work. 
Neither does `npm start -- --inspect`

Comment: may sound silly, but have you installed node-inspect?

Comment: what version of npm you are using? What are you trying to do? For Node 10, you can just use the debugger.

Comment: also if youre trying to debug network calls, i recommend https://nodemon.io/

Answer (score 16):

npm supports a `node-options` config value which is passed through using the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable.  This environment variable is interpreted by NodeJS 8+.  So if your package.json looks something like:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node src/index.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

then you can use

```
npm --node-options --inspect run dev
```