# How to debug a node js project on chrome which run by npm run serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, package.json

Normally we do like node --inspect your_file.js,

eg: `node --inspect server.js`

But my project now uses the command `"npm run serve"` to start the server 
so how can I debug it on chrome?

In package.json scripts  is defined as below

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
  "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
  "start": "npm run shell",
  "deploy_bkp": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  "logs": "firebase functions:log",
  "test": "mocha  --timeout 10000 --reporter spec"
},
```

Comment: Can you not debug it in the code editor that you are using?

Comment: I am using vscode, is it possible to debug node in vscode?

Comment: Added an answer below, please check

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'node --inspect' with the path to firebase in the node_modules folder.

Something like the below?

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "serve": "node --inspect .\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js serve --only functions",
  "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
  "start": "npm run shell",
  "deploy_bkp": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  "logs": "firebase functions:log",
  "test": "mocha  --timeout 10000 --reporter spec"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VS Code, you can use the built-in debugger to debug your NodeJS project. You just need to set up your `launch.json` file. looking at your `package.json` scripts, something like this should work.

```
 {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/functions/src/index.js",
    }
  ]
}
```

Replace the name of the file with the file that is your main script instead of `index.js`, for example, `server.js`

After this, just set your breakpoint and start debugging!

Comment: But this is just how a js file is debugging, which will not work in my case, can you please check my script

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to debug my test files, and I faced a similar situation. All i had to do was

```
node --inspect path/to/binary file_name.js_or_subcommand
```

e.g.

```
node --inspect node_modules/.bin/firebase serve
```

This would be enough, and you would be able to connect with the debugger using chrome.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this answer sure works for me:
[Use `npm start` with --inspect flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614219/use-npm-start-with-inspect-flag)

in short: `npm --node-options --inspect run dev`